# Are downloads from spark distribution archive often slow?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to download spark-hadoop distribution from the website - `https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.1.2/`. Often I find that the downloads from this site are generally slow. Is it due to some generic issue with the site itself?

That the download is slow I have verified in two ways -

- In Colab I have run the command `!wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.1.2/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz` which keeps running often for more than say 10 minutes. While at other times it executes within 1 minute.
- From the website I tried downloading it and even then the download speed is extremely slow occasionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It maybe because

- You download multiple times
- You download from non-browser, for example curl/wget
- Your location is physically far from file server or network is unstable.
- or something else. for example file server is slow

I think most of public server has kind a "safe guard" to prevent DDoS, So their "Safe guard" control download traffic per sec.
I faced similar issue, when I download from browser, it took 1min, but It took 10min when I use curl